# What to put in a future work schedule section's title of my pre-thesis

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology

I'm writing my doctor's degree "qualification" (that's what we call in Brazil), I'm not sure if something similar is required in other countries, but it's like a pre-thesis that you have to present after 2 years of work. Even tho I'm in Brazil I'm writing it in English, it just makes it much easier to write papers afterwards.

There is a section/chapter where I must describe what is my schedule for the next years to finish the research to get my degree, but I'm not sure how one would call that in English. In Portuguese it's called "cronograma", but "chronogram" in English means something completely different.

Any suggestions? Is it a common practice in other countries?

[Side question]
what is it called the event of presenting your thesis to the examining board(??)?. In Brazil it is called "the defense"-of-[title].

Comment: This is not an answer, but a suggestion for additional words to research: *chronology, schedule, timeline*. Also please ask only one question per page. If you have two questions, feel free to post two separate questions.

Comment: Since what you are asking is specific to academic practice, you might want to look at the site [academia.se] as another possible place to post your question. If you want to try another site, please ask for migration, or else delete the original before re-asking the question on the other site. See: “[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site? – Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/171321)”, an article from the Stack Exchange FAQ.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @MetaEd, about the two questions thing, it's kinda of an off-topic question that is related to the original, I think it's ok, even more since it's not really important that I get the second one answered. My line of thought was that, the person that has an answer to the main question will have the answer to the side one as well ;D

Comment: I might try the migration thing if this ends up unanswered here @MetaEd, thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked a bit more around and it seems that the title "Work Plan and Implications" or just "Work Plan" might do the job well.

Thank you @MetaEd for suggestions.

[marked yet still open for further discussion]